# Why don't only typing controller name in the browser redirects to the action that I have defined in the route config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I have this controller Login which has a get method named Login.

Now If I type a controller name in browser link then it should automatically pick Login method among other methods or If I type action name without controller then it should pick.

I have done this in RouteConfig:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute
                (
                    name: "Login",
                    url: "Login",
                    defaults: new {controller= "Login", action= "Login", id= UrlParameter.Optional }
                );


        }
```

But it doesn't work. But if I place it above the default route then it works but the problem is that upon loading the project it directly goes to login page.

Comment: The order of your routes matter - swap them (`Login` needs to be before the `Default`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's true like I said that works but then it gets opened by default upon loading the project which I don't want. I want it to get opened after typing and hitting enter

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok it works, yeah. But when I mention {controller}/{action}/{id} in url in maproute then it opens the page upon loading the project but not else, why?

Comment: What do you mean it gets opened by default?

Comment: like when I just type :http://localhost:13924/ then it opens Login by default but it is when I mention  {controller}/{action}/{id} in url in maproute but not If i only write Login in URL, like in the question

Comment: Either you have set that as the default in VS or you have an `[Authorize]` attribute on the other method

Comment: @StephenMuecke No sir, i checked, none of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171458/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-stacky).